# C Function to find the closest number in a file

Tags: c

I'm making a C function where I need to find the closest standard resistance value in a file after calculating the equivalent. `req1` is the equivalent resistance value.
Right now it only works if the equivalent value is equal to some value in the file.

My problem is how can I, reading the file, calculate which is the closest number? For example if `req1` = 1.4, after reading the file, it should give me the number 1.5.

What the file looks like (standard resistances):

```
1.0 
1.1 
1.2
1.3
1.5
```

Code:

```
void CalcClosest(char *req1)
{
    FILE* file;
    char temp[1000];

    file = fopen("StandardResistance.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Error!");
        return;
    }
    while(fgets(temp, 1000, file)!=NULL) {
        if((strstr(temp, req1)) != NULL) {
            printf("Standard resistance equivalent: ");
            printf("%s", temp);
        }

        // code to find the closest number

    }

    fclose(file); 
}
```

Comment: If you want the closest `strstr()` is certainly a bad choice.

Comment: Indeed, when looking to do something with numbers, rarely is leaving them in text form appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fscanf()` and if you want the value closest above the *search* value, this will do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main(void)
{
    float search;
    float current;
    float found;
    float difference;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("StandardResistance.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return -1;
    search = 1.4;
    found = 0.0;
    difference = FLT_MAX;
    while (fscanf(file, "%f", &current) == 1)
    {
        if (fabs(search - current) < difference)
        {
            found = current;
            difference = fabs(search - current);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    fprintf(stderr, "found: %f\n", found);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `difference = 0.0;` be initialised to `FLT_MAX` along with the use of `fabs()`, to find the closest match?

Comment: @WeatherVane Good thinking, didn't think of that.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's fine, my thoughts weren't dedicated to it anyway. Thank you! But there is an ambiguity since it can find the larger or smaller closest value and I think the OP wanted the larger. But when I saw your edit I realized that my code would fail sometimes, and then I did redo your edit because it makes the answer almost correct, just that I am really busy right now.

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to do it is: put all your numbers into an array as doubles(see [atof function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atof.htm) and [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) to manage the array), calculate the absolute value of the difference between `req1` and every value of the array and find the one which is closest to zero (this can be done with a simple `for` loop) as follows:

```
double lower = array[0];
for(unsigned i = 0; i < NumberOfEntries; i++) {
    if(array[i] < lower) { lower = array[i]; }
}
```

Comment: No need to save the values. Just do the comparison on the fly and keep the closest value.

Comment: Edited the answer ;-)